# look through a very large numbers (1.2e+34) in Python

Tags: python, loops, data-science, large-data

Already looked at Google and past questions in here and couldn't find a simple and well-explained answer.

**How to loop through a large number in python?**

e.g. I would like to check how long it will take to loop between 1 and 1.2e+34 and print the final result.

Not sure how to write for look/while loop for this and I have no idea how to write 1.2e+34 in python language **(For i = 1 to i = ?)**.

Comment: Why do you think that enumerating through a "large" number would be any different than through a "small" number?

Comment: Perhaps you think that enumerating through a large number is different than through a small number because you tried `range(1, 1.2e34)` and got `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Or perhaps not. We can't tell because you didn't tell us. Sharing your unsuccessful approaches is usually useful.

Comment: I was trying for i in xrange(1, int(1.2e34)+1): in python 2.7 and was getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python understands `1.2e34`, as a float, but you can cast it to an int. `int(1.2e34)`.

If you want to loop between 1 and `n` inclusive, you would normally use [`range(1, n+1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Thus, in Python 3:

```
for i in range(1, int(1.2e34)+1):
    print(i)   # or do whatever you want
```

--

As FHTMitchell pointed out, in Python 2, the value is too large for `range` or `xrange`. You could use a `while` loop instead.

```
i = 1
while i <= 1.2e34:
    print i    # or do whatever you want
    i += 1
```

Comment: `for i in xrange(1, int(1.2e34)+1):` fails in python 2 because `xrange` accepts `int`s only, not `long`s, which `int(1.2e34)` is. I think you'd have to do the old `i = 0L; while i < 1.2e43: stuff(); i += 1` trick. Or upgrade to python 3 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have an answer as to *how* you'd do it, but you really need to think about if you *should* do it. On my, not slow machine, this code in iPython (py 3.6):

```
def f(n):
   for i in range(10 ** n):
      pass

%timeit f(6)
```

produces

```
10 loops, best of 3: 20.4 ms per loop
```

So if you want to loop between `1` and `1.2e34` that will take 1.2e34 / 0.0204 = 5.77e35 seconds or roughly [10^18 times the age of the universe](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5.77e35%20seconds%20%2F%20%5Buniverse%20age%5D).

I don't think you want to be doing that...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
i = 1L
while True:
    i += 1
    if i == int(1.2e34):
        print(i)
        break
```